# Cannot connect to H2 Database with given route from Jhipster

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jhipster, h2

[image]

I have a Java Spring project that is running the H2 database, and after running it with `mvnw`, and going to http://localhost:8080/h2-console, the above image is what I see.

Other people on my team said it works just fine for them, and we are on the same code repo and on master.

I have tried in Chrome, Edge, and Firefox with the same results. I have also double checked that JavaScript is turned on and working.

The only thing logged to the console is when I have spring security logging set to DEBUG and then this is what is shown:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
2020-10-19 16:14:18.376 DEBUG 13932 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /h2-console/login.jsp' doesn't match 'OPTIONS /*
*'
2020-10-19 16:14:18.376 DEBUG 13932 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/h2-console/login.jsp'; against
'/app/**/*.{js,html}'
2020-10-19 16:14:18.376 DEBUG 13932 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/h2-console/login.jsp'; against
'/i18n/**'
2020-10-19 16:14:18.377 DEBUG 13932 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/h2-console/login.jsp'; against
'/content/**'
2020-10-19 16:14:18.377 DEBUG 13932 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/h2-console/login.jsp'; against
'/h2-console/**'
2020-10-19 16:14:18.377 DEBUG 13932 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /h2-console/login.jsp has an empty filter list
2020-10-19 16:14:18.409 DEBUG 13932 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /h2-console/stylesheet.css' doesn't match 'OPTIO
NS /**'
2020-10-19 16:14:18.409 DEBUG 13932 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/h2-console/stylesheet.css'; aga
inst '/app/**/*.{js,html}'
2020-10-19 16:14:18.409 DEBUG 13932 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/h2-console/stylesheet.css'; aga
inst '/i18n/**'
2020-10-19 16:14:18.409 DEBUG 13932 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/h2-console/stylesheet.css'; aga
inst '/content/**'
2020-10-19 16:14:18.409 DEBUG 13932 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/h2-console/stylesheet.css'; aga
inst '/h2-console/**'
2020-10-19 16:14:18.410 DEBUG 13932 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /h2-console/stylesheet.css has an empty filter list
```

What could be the cause of this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add unsafe inline to the code,  where you set CSP headers

Comment: Was being blocked by backend CSP settings. ```script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';``` fixed the issue.

Comment: For example, might be in the ContentSecurityPolicyFilter class if you are using Spring Boot/JHipster.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Java script is not enabled in your chrome browser, could you please try the below details?

https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/how-to-enable-javascript/chrome

Comment: JavaScript is enabled on all 3 of the browsers I tried.

Comment: Does the browser console show some errors? Can zou try to open the h2 login page directly? I think it is `h2-console/login.jsp` (but not sure).

Comment: There is an error in the console: ```Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-uv309pViOsJwkLZHFLoia40Jog8aOO+wqBfMt3y/Aqc='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.```